# phpmyadmin how to set 2 col of auto-increment

Tags: phpmyadmin

I already created my database and table. 
One of my table require 2 field to be auto increment.
One of the col is set as my primary key so there's no problem.
However, I need another col to be auto increment as well.

Anybody knows how to do the setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What problem are you trying to solve? Are both columns going to have exactly the same value (as is implied if you start counting an auto increment column at the same time)? It doesn't make much sense why you would want to do this (even if there's an offset, it's a known value that can be computed when running the SELECT query). A fuller description of what you're trying to accomplish would help us try to solve your problem instead of simply answering the question as asked.

However, basically no, MySQL doesn't allow you to do that. See https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/35483/33241 for some greater explanation and other ideas.

Depending on your end goal, there are some workarounds or alternatives that would work. Mostly I'm thinking of a trigger; after insert you can increment or compute a value to store in the second column, but as I said before I don't see a use case for storing one since it can be computed later.

Comment: Appreciated your help. Problem solved, i set as my foreign key. Thanks for the information given.